# WCF named pipe between C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, ipc, pipe

I implemented [this simple example](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) of using WCF named pipe communication. It works great. Both server and client are implemented in C#.

BUT...

When I implement the client part in VB.NET (and leaves the server unchanged), the string parameter disappears in the pipe. When it arrives at the server it is null. I tried to change the parameter type to an int and then it becomes zero at server side.

My plan is to make this communication more complex, using reference types, and this is not a good start. And I can't figure out why, these basic types are equivalent in C#/VB.NET.

I am implementing this on the .NET 4.0 Framework.

Can someone bring some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: Without seeing your code nobody can tell you what's wrong...

Comment: This example to me seems to only put every methods as his own endpoint. that how i see it. Code seems rather complicated for such easy task. if that's really the functioning you are looking for i suggest you search for "Restful Service". Most example out there will have individual endpoint per function but it's not necessary either but i would look like something like this : `http:\\server\myservice?myAwesomeFunction`

Comment: Dominic, the thing is that the method on server side is reached ok but the parameter value is lost in the pipe. So the code is not really the issue here.